# Prove that the following recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}(1-x_n)$ is monotonic, bounded and find its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given the following recursive sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}(1-x_n)$ , $n\geq1$ , $x_1=a$ and $a\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$, prove by induction that it is monotonic, bounded, convergent and find its limit.

I've tried already to solve this problem in my introduction to calculus class and i'm don't getting it. It would be very helpful for me if someone could give me an insight on it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please provide a little more context: why is this problem important for you, and what you've already tried to solve it?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri done! New at this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_{n+1}= \frac{x_n(1- x_n)}{2}= x_n\left(\frac{1- x_n}{2}\right)$

In particular, $x_1= x_0\left(\frac{1- x_0}{2}\right)$.  Since $0< x_0< \frac{1}{2}$, $-\frac{1}{2}< x_0< 0$, $1- \frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{2}< 1- x_0< 1$, $\frac{1}{4}< \frac{1- x_0}{2}< \frac{1}{2}$ so $0< \frac{x_0}{4}< x_{n+1}< \frac{x_0}{2}< x_0< \frac{1}{2}$.

That is the first step in showing that the sequence is decreasing.  For the induction step, assume that, for some k, $0< x_{k+1}< x_k$.  Now look at $x_{k+2}= x_k\left(\frac{1- x_k}{2}\right)$.  Since $0< x_{k+1}< x_k< \frac{1}{2}$, as above, $\frac{1- x_k}{2}< \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM inequality: $0 <x_n \le \dfrac{1}{8}$ hence bounded, and $x_n - x_{n-1} = -\dfrac{1}{2} \left(x_{n-1}^2+x_{n-1}\right)< 0$. So it is bounded below ( and above )and is decreasing and thus the limit $L$ exists and $L = \dfrac{L(1-L)}{2}\implies 2L = L - L^2\implies L(1+L) = 0 \implies L = 0, -1$. We take $L = 0$ since $L \ge 0$.